# Scrollbar horizontal has not applying CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I applied CSS for scrollbar but its not working on horizontal scrollbar. I applied already in CSS file for body::scrollbar but applied only vertical scrollbar in reactjs.

I already applied CSS but its working only on vertical scroll.
[image]

Comment: Can you share some code snippets and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}
```

Height will give you what you wanted. Change 'px' according to your need.